# supervisorctl always reports error: ERROR (no such file)

Tags: django, nginx, supervisord, django-supervisor

I deploy my django project with uwsgi、supervisor and nginx.
but I have added my program like above in the /etc/supervisord.conf.

```
[program:JZAssist]
command=-E uwsgi --ini /home/work/xxxx/uwsgi.ini
directory=/home/work/xxxx
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

and my uwsgi.ini content is:

```
[uwsgi] 
socket = :8000 
chdir = /home/work/xxxx 
module = xxxx.wsgi 
master = true 
processes = 4 
vacuum = true
```

xxxx is my project name.

I run `supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisord.conf restart all` in the cmd.
And it shows

```
xxxx: ERROR (no such file)
```

/tmp/supervisord.log part of content:

```
2017-02-24 23:31:41,433 INFO gave up: JZAssist entered FATAL state,         too many start retries too quickly
2017-02-24 23:52:29,940 WARN Failed to clean up '/tmp/JZAssist-stderr---supervisor-goPZyS.log'
2017-02-24 23:52:29,940 WARN Failed to clean up '/tmp/JZAssist-stdout---supervisor-WtfJcp.log'
2017-02-24 23:52:57,535 WARN Failed to clean up '/tmp/JZAssist-stderr---supervisor-goPZyS.log'
2017-02-24 23:52:57,535 WARN Failed to clean up '/tmp/JZAssist-stdout---supervisor-WtfJcp.log'
2017-02-24 23:52:57,541 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-02-24 23:52:57,541 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-02-24 23:52:57,542 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2017-02-24 23:52:57,543 CRIT could not write pidfile /tmp/supervisord.pid
2017-02-24 23:52:58,544 INFO spawnerr: can't find command '-E'
2017-02-24 23:52:59,546 INFO spawnerr: can't find command '-E'
2017-02-25 00:46:59,234 WARN Failed to clean up '/tmp/JZAssist-stderr---supervisor-goPZyS.log'
2017-02-25 00:46:59,234 WARN Failed to clean up '/tmp/JZAssist-stdout---supervisor-WtfJcp.log'
```

I don't know why it will report error like that.I can run my django project with runserver.so what the file is missing?

Comment: What is the first `-E` element in the command ?

Comment: I use -E to keep environment variables when using SUDO

Comment: What is the content of your log file and what is the log level for supervisor?

Comment: loglevel=info, and the log I added above

Answer (score 8):

On your `command=` line, you've specified the program to run as `-E`, which supervisor can't find to execute.

When creating a file for the job, the command line should be executable as a shell command, and should not rely on internal commands for a given shell. For example, I had trouble with one that started with:

`source /path/to/python/virtual/environment/bin/activate && ...`

but `source` is a bash builtin. I needed to change it to read:

`bash -c 'source /path/to/python/virtual/environment/bin/activate && ...`

This way, the executable file that supervisor can find and run is `bash`.

In your case, it appears uwsgi should be the first thing after `command=`.

You mentioned that you're using the `-E` flag to preserve environment variables when you run `sudo`, but supervisor won't need `sudo`

Comment: YEs, it's a bit of a "confusing" error, especially as there wasn't something in the log files explaining it properly.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error message, but in my case it turned out I'd specified a user in my job definition that hadn't been created on the server.

```
[program:my-task]
user=this-user-didnt-exist
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I had `command="/bin/python3.8 main.py"` in my conf.d/mysite.conf file.

When i removed the `""`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well trying to run a shell script via supervisord, you need to use `/bin/sh myscript.sh`:

```ini
command=/bin/sh myscript.sh
```